# Strange behavior when attempting to delete the first node of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am writing a delete function to delete an entry in a waiting list by searching for the parameters of classroom, first name, last name. The function works for any entry that is located around the middle or tail of the linked list. However, if the entry that is searched for is the first node, I receive strange characters in the output, with a crash happening if I attempt to quit the program after this.

```
struct request* delete_from_list(struct request *list){

    if(list == NULL)
    {
        printf("The list is empty so delete can not be performed");
    }

    struct request *ptr = list;
    struct request *ptr1 = NULL;
    char classroom[ROOM_LEN];
    char first[NAME_LEN+1];
    char last[NAME_LEN+1];

    printf("Enter the class room: \n");
    read_line(classroom, ROOM_LEN);
    printf("Enter the child's first name: \n");
    read_line(first, NAME_LEN);
    printf("Enter the child's last name: \n");
    read_line(last, NAME_LEN);

    //Check for the entry in the list
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(ptr->classroom, classroom) == 0)
            if(strcmp(ptr->first, first) == 0)
                if(strcmp(ptr->last, last) == 0)
                    break;

        ptr1 = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    if(ptr != NULL)
    {
        if(ptr == list)
            list = list->next;
        else
            ptr1->next = ptr->next;

        free(ptr);

        printf("\n%s %s is deleted from the waiting list for %s classroom", first, last, classroom);
    }

    else if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s %s is not found in the waiting list for %s classroom", first, last, classroom);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: case 'd': delete_from_list(wait_list);
The user is asked for an operation code and it goes into a switch.

Comment: It worked, thank you for the help.

Comment: @user3121023 write that as an answer.